# jquery post in new opened window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page where I enter a text in an input, it is a simple form. I have a button and when I hit the button, is it possible to open another page and post the data to this new window via jquery. I am not talking about ajax here because I want to open a new window and go to that new page holding the post form.

So I have page 1 with form and input 1. I enter test in input 1 and then if I hit submit, it will open a new php page where there is a

```
$_POST['temp']
```

And it will be filled in so that the code executes automatically. In fact, this is to avoid entering everything in the url and going to that url.

It seems I was not clear enough. I know how to do it with a form and a submit button. But I would like to submit the form via jquery so when I hit a button or something else that will be intercepted by my javascript, it will look up the input and then redirect to the other page and post with data I want.

Comment: Uhm, this is what forms do? If you want to redirect somewhere you set the forms `action` attribute ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp - Look at the code of 'Try yourself' to understand how action attribute works. Hope it helped.

Comment: I m saying when using jquery !!!

Comment: You cannot have $_POST['temp'] without sending the value to the server first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to access parent window form input value from a child window (popup) opened by the parent.
If that is the case I suggest you look at `window.opener` property
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

If you have a parent window like this:

HTML:

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input type="text" id="testVariable" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('http://www.yourdomain.com/chilwindow.php', 'ChildWindow', 'menubar=0,resizable=1,location=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,toolbar=0,width=580,height=520');
    });
});
```

Then in your child window/popup (http://www.yourdomain.com/chilwindow.php) you should be able to access you parent window like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var testVariableNew = window.opener.$("#testVariable").val();
    console.log('Got value from parent window: ' + testVariableNew);
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var testVariableNew = $('#testVariable', window.opener.document).val();
    console.log('Got value from parent window: ' + testVariableNew);
});
```

If you want to do a POST request do the following:

```
$( "#testForm" ).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var myVariable = $(this).find("#testVariable").val();
  var myUrl = $(this).attr("action");
  var posting = $.post( myUrl , { temp: myVariable } );
  posting.done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The jquery.form.js plugin does exactly what you want.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
                alert("The script said: "+response); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
```